# Iis it correct code or not - Pine script ML Code Prediction gives unexpected results

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I edited my script further using lastguru trading view code. The predictions are coming, but as good as expected.

I just want to know my code is correct or not.

Am I going in the correct path. Please anybody put a light on my way as I'm blindly doing things ...

Here is the code:

[image: Screenshot of the indicator.]

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at
https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © subikshababu

//@version=5
indicator("ema ML",overlay = false)

em1=ta.ema(ta.ema(hlc3,2),3)
em2=ta.ema(ta.ema(hlc3,5),8)
em3=ta.ema(ta.ema(hlc3,8),13)
em4=ta.ema(ta.ema(hlc3,13),21)


plot(em1,color = color.red,linewidth = 2)
plot(em2,color = color.green,linewidth = 2)
plot(em3,color = color.blue,linewidth = 2)

arrsma=array.from(em1,em2,em3)
avgem=array.avg(arrsma)
plot(avgem,color=color.black,linewidth = 3)


src=close>open?1 : close<open?-1:0


/////////
// kNN //
/////////
SRC=avgem

// Define storage arrays for: parameter 1, parameter 2, price, result (up = 1; down = -1)
var knn1 = array.new_float(1, 0)
var knn2 = array.new_float(1, 0)
var knnp = array.new_float(1, 0)
var knnr = array.new_float(1, 0)

// Store the previous trade; buffer the current one until results are in
_knnStore(p1, p2) =>
    var prevp1 = 0.0
    var prevp2 = 0.0
    var prevsrc = 0.0

    array.push(knn1, prevp1)
    array.push(knn2, prevp2)
    array.push(knnp, prevsrc)
    array.push(knnr, src >= src[1] ? 1 : -1)

    prevp1 := p1
    prevp2 := p2
    prevsrc := src
    prevsrc

// Get neighbours by getting k smallest distances from the distance array, and then getting all results with these distances
_knnGet(arr1, arr2, k) =>
    sarr = array.copy(arr1)
    array.sort(sarr)
    ss = array.slice(sarr, 0, math.min(k, array.size(sarr)))
    m = array.max(ss)
    out = array.new_float(0)
    for i = 0 to array.size(arr1) - 1 by 1
        if array.get(arr1, i) <= m
            array.push(out, array.get(arr2, i))
    out

// Create a distance array from the two given parameters
_knnDistance(p1, p2) =>
    dist = array.new_float(0)
    n = array.size(knn1) - 1
    for i = 0 to n by 1
        d = math.sqrt(math.pow(p1 - array.get(knn1, i), 2) + math.pow(p2 - array.get(knn2, i), 2))
        array.push(dist, d)
    dist

// Make a prediction, finding k nearest neighbours
_knn(p1, p2, k) =>
    slice = _knnGet(_knnDistance(p1, p2), array.copy(knnr), k)
    knn = array.sum(slice)
    knn

////////////
// Inputs //
////////////


// When DIST is 0, KNN default was 23
KNN = input(title='kNN nearest neighbors (k)', defval=1)
float DIST = input(title='kNN minimum difference', defval=.5)
BACKGROUND = input(title='Draw background', defval=false)

////////
// MA //
////////

buysell(x,y)=>
    _knnStore(x, y)
    filter = _knn(x, y, KNN)
    buy= (( filter >= DIST))?1 : 0
    sell= ((filter <= -DIST))?1:0
    [buy,sell]

[buy,sell]=buysell(em1,em2)
[buy1,sell1]=buysell(em1,em3)
//[buy2,sell2]=buysell(em1,em4)


buycum=buy+buy1
sellcum=sell+sell1

buysig=buycum>sellcum
sellsig=sellcum>buycum


plotshape(buysig,style = shape.circle,location = location.top,color = color.green)

plotshape(sellsig,style = shape.circle,location = location.top,color = color.red)
```

Comment: why i am not able to add more emas to the code; the script takes long time to load, [buy,sell]=buysell(em1,em2)
[buy1,sell1]=buysell(em1,em3)
//[buy2,sell2]=buysell(em1,em4)

i commented the 4 th ema Ultimately i want to add more emas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To speed up the code and avoid the time limit error, you can limit the size of the arrays.
If the array size goes up, your for-to loop takes more and more time and you risk a time out limit from pinescript.
Here is the part of code you must change ;

```
// Store the previous trade; buffer the current one until results are in
LimitArraySize = 10
_knnStore(p1, p2) =>
    var prevp1 = 0.0
    var prevp2 = 0.0
    var prevsrc = 0.0

    array.push(knn1, prevp1)
    array.push(knn2, prevp2)
    array.push(knnp, prevsrc)
    array.push(knnr, src >= src[1] ? 1 : -1)
    if array.size(knn1) > LimitArraySize
        array.remove(knn1, 0)
        array.remove(knn2, 0)
        array.remove(knnp, 0)
        array.remove(knnr, 0)
```

You can play with the LimitArraySize value to size until where it works.